# Accessing list of all sprites in textmeshpro

Tags: unity, editors, text-mesh-pro

I am trying to make a tool for selecting icons from textmesh pro in the inspector using a custom property drawer, to select the desired sprite directly instead of having to remember the name.

While TMP_SpriteAsset in certain old versions of TMPro seem to have a static reference to the default sprite asset, that does not seem to be the case in newer versions.

How can I still get such a reference to the default assets and the names of the sprites stored in them?